# magento how to add product from category page without reloading

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am having quickview extension in my theme for adding products and it works fine. But I need to add products without reloading the page everytime. Although the top minicart is also working properly.

I have tried using jquery on add-to-cart button on my category list page, it is adding though but again I have to reload it to get back on the previous page.

Please can anyone help with by suggesting step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-mini-cart-ajax-cart.html for asynchronous addtocart action. (as i just used it recently and works fine in my case.)
You can later customize as according to your need.

Comment: I tried installing it but its giving an error.And I just need to stop page reloading after add-to-cart button is hit.Rest everything is working fine.

Comment: what is the error ? Could you please elaborate ? via the module it page doesn't reloads. All things goes asynchronous along with the success message

Comment: its disturbing whole layout of page and even its button is not displaying,add-to-cart button is not working.I already having an extension similar to above.

Comment: Its just that the functionality in popup for add to cart ,I need to add it on category list page with add to cart button